# Error: Request failed with status code 403

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my react.js code. and console is like << POST http://localhost:4000/api/main/date 403 (Forbidden) >>
What is the problem? Plz help me

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { INPUT_DATE } from "./types";


export function inputDate(dataTosubmit) {
  const request = axios
    .post("http://localhost:4000/api/main/date", dataTosubmit)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .catch((error)=>console.log(error));

  return {
    type: INPUT_DATE,
    payload: request,
  };
}
```

Comment: can you show the error message and the response?

Comment: Seems like a server side issue.